How to prove the rank of adjoint matrix can only be 0, 1, n
If A $\in M_{n}(\mathbb R)$, how to prove the rank of the adjoint matrix ($\widetilde{A}$) is either 0, 1 or n? 
I'm a beginner of linear algebra. I know that if rank(A) = n, it's obvious that rank($\widetilde{A}$) = n.
And if rank(A) $\le$ n-2, its cafctors in n-1 order equal zero.
so the problem is when the rank of A is n-1. I've tried some times by considering the vectors of A. But it doesn't work.

$A \widetilde{A}=\det(A) diaginal(1,1,\cdots,1)$
